# Perform additional tasks within a maven build

Tags: java, maven

I am wondering about how to perform specific tasks during a maven build: I would like to use some of my code to do some preprocessing on the data that I am shipping in the resulting jar. Generally given some `input.xml` in `src/main/resources` I would like to be able to call a java function / main method to obtain a file `output.xml` which is included available as a resource (and probably placed in `target/classes/...`). Using `Makefile`s this would correspond to an additional rule, I guess this could be done with an ant task as well (though I have never used ant myself). can I add such a rule to a maven project as well?

Comment: ahh, you enter a difficult terrain. [Here](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/why-build-your-java-projects-with-gradle/240168608) is some reading to keep you company. The main lesson is that the pattern in maven to do extra things like this is solved with the creation or use of an existing plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Maven Exec Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) to run arbitrary Java code during your build.

If you should happen to have your tasks formulated as Ant targets, the [Maven Antrun Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) can be used to run those.